# C# - Access image stream inside xap in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have a silverlight 5 project called Kinemat.AuthoringTool. Inside this project i have a folder called Backgrounds and there i have some images (their Build Action is `Content`). I want to access an image's stream and then upload that image on a server. After some research on msdn i use the following code:

```
StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = 
                      Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("PathToPutHere"));
Stream imageStream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;
```

of course using the path "/Backgrounds/imageName" does not work. What is the correct path then?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, make the images with the build property of `Embeded` and path to it via namespace and name in the containing dll. I have created such an image extractor for a stream (*Can be used outside of Silverlight*)

```
public static Stream GetImage(string resourceName)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

    if (stream == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(
             $"No resource with name {resourceName} in {assembly.FullName}");

    return stream;
}
```